# How to access a proxy enabled internet with ssh tunneling?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, connection-refused

I have two pc (**A & B,** Both are running ubuntu 16.04) that are connected through Local Network. **PC-A has Internet connection.** I want to browse internet in PC-B using ssh tunneling.

I used the command in PC-B -

```
ssh -D 9999 user@IP_ADDRESS
```

Then i set **HTTP, HTTPS, FTP Proxy** empty and **SOCKS Proxy** "localhost" and port 9999.

If PC-A has Internet connection which is **not** requires proxy setup , then i can browse network in PC-B using above command.

But if PC-A has Internet conenction which requires **HTTP Proxy** "xxx.yy.zz.zz" and port 8080 then i can't browse internet using the above command and terminal shows following error:

`"channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused".`

What should i do ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to my own question is :**

If PC-A has Internet connection with proxy (proxy_ip:port) and you want to access PC-A Internet connection in PC-B through local network connection using ssh then execute this command in terminal :

```
ssh -L random_port:proxy_ip:port username_A@ip_Address_A
```

Let's take an example :

PC-A :

- username : linus
- IP Address : 192.168.55.55
- Runs on proxy: 192.168.11.11
- Runs on port: 8080

chose a random port, 7856 (Randomly)

then in PC-B

```
ssh -L 7856:192.168.11.11:8080 linus@192.168.55.55
```

Then change the network setting :

- HTTP/HTTPS PROXY : localhost or 172.0.0.1
- PORT       : random_port (In this case 7856)

Now You have Internet Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running a proxy server, maybe squid, on PC-A?  Then you can create a tunnel from PC-B on a given port to the input port on PC-A of the squid daemon.

Then you can configure squid to either use another upstream proxy (http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/using-a-parent-proxy-with-squid/) or directly connect to the internet depending on what you need.